# Choose language for tts depending on translation state

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm building a simple app that can read string resources to the user. Eventually these resources will be translated (into more than currently two languages, english (default resources) and german.

Now my problem is to choose the correct language for the TTS engine, when no translations for the user's system locale exist.

Is there any way to determine whether a string is translated resp. it does not come from the default `values/strings.xml` file?

**Update:** The object is that e.g. no german strings are synthesized with an english voice.

Comment: You can try AChartEngine. This library has pinch zoom for graph as well.

Comment: @seema....what has this to do with tts? Or did I miss something...?

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if it is exactly what You need and if I understand You the right way. I guess You want to determine first, which locale the users device uses, right? Then, there is a method that could be what You need:

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayName();
```

With `getResources().getConfiguration()` You will get **"current configuration that is in effect for this resource object"** and with the Configuration locale you get **"current user preference for the locale, corresponding to locale resource qualifier"** (API quotes). Then You will retrive the used language with `getDisplayName()`:

**Returns this locale's language name, country name, and variant, localized to locale. The exact output form depends on whether this locale corresponds to a specific language, script, country and variant.**

I guess, You get an output like "English" or "English (united states)" or similar. This is described here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayName%28%29

With this information, You can determine if Your translation for the devices country is used.

Comment: OK, so you suggest manually testing whether the user's locale is in a (manually updated) list of already translated languages. I also thought of that approach but thought there might be a more automated way to do this.

Comment: Yes, I think you have to do it in that way. At least, to me another way is not known to me.